# Using Jquery UI sortable to sort 2 list at once

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a very simple question. Using Jquery UI's sortable, I want to sort two Identical list at once. Let say I have two lists of 5 draggable objects each. Sorting one list will also sort the other list in an identical manner. Is there a way to do this with Jquery UI?

I have something like this to start...

```
<div class="list1">
    <div class="quote1">1</div>
    <div class="quote2">2</div>
    <div class="quote3">3</div>
    <div class="quote4">4</div>
    <div class="quote5">5</div>
</div>

<div class="list2">
    <div class="quote1">1</div>
    <div class="quote2">2</div>
    <div class="quote3">3</div>
    <div class="quote4">4</div>
    <div class="quote5">5</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".list1" ).sortable();
    $( ".list1" ).disableSelection();

    $( ".list2" ).sortable();
    $( ".list2" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use a sort event callback to update the second list. Off topic: Your code above could be simplified to `$('.list1, .list2').sortable().disableSelection();`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use one routine for both lists if you use IDs to identify each list, and classes to identify all lists that can be sorted.

In the jsFiddle demo, please note that change to your HTML.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3fFG/)</kbd>

Here is working code:

```
var lst, pre, post; //lst == name of list being sorted

$(".sortlist").sortable({
    start:function(event, ui){
        pre = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        lst = $(this).attr('id');
        post = ui.item.index();
        other = (lst == 'list1') ? 'list2' : 'list1';
        //Use insertBefore if moving UP, or insertAfter if moving DOWN
        if (post > pre) {
            $('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertAfter('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }else{
            $('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertBefore('#'+other+ ' div:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

---

Explanation:

1. When you drag an item, the first thing that happens is the `start:` function. In there, we grab the current index position of the item and store it as `pre`
2. When the item is dropped, the `stop:` function is executed. In here, we want to get:
   a. Which list we are sorting
   b. The NEW index position (so now we have the START position and the STOP positions)
   c. The name of the *other* list
3. **IF** `post` (the NEW index position) is greater than `pre` (the ORIGINAL position):
   a. We are moving the item DOWN, so...
   b. When we programatically relocate the item in the other list we must use `insertAfter`
   **ELSE**
   a. We are moving the item UP in the list, so
   b. We must use the `insertBefore` method when moving the item in the other list.
4. Inside the `if` statement, variable values tell jQuery which item to move and where to put it. It may help to see the code WITHOUT the variables. So, as an example, if I move the first item in List1 to the bottom of the list, here is what we want jQuery to do to the other list:

`$('#list2 div:eq(0)').insertAfter('#list2 div:eq(4)');`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Its definitely working in the jsFiddle, but my brain cant seems to understand what your code is doing at all starting at the If statement, haha.

Comment: See further explanation added to answer

Answer (score 2):

This solution works in real time as you are dragging:

```
var currentIndex;
$(function() {
    $( ".list" ).sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) { 
            currentIndex = ui.helper.index();
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) { 
            var indexCount = ui.item.parent().find('div:not(.ui-sortable-helper)');
            var sortClass = '.'+ui.item.attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            var parent = $('.list').not(ui.item.parent());
            if(currentIndex > ui.placeholder.index()){
                parent.find('div').eq(indexCount.index(ui.placeholder)).before(parent.find(sortClass));
            }
            else
                parent.find('div').eq(indexCount.index(ui.placeholder)).after(parent.find(sortClass));
            currentIndex = ui.placeholder.index();
        }
    });
    $( ".list" ).disableSelection();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/EXk7T/2/

Comment: @YanZhao A solution that shows the changes as the list changes when dragging..  Had fun getting this to work.

Comment: Very nicely done Trevor. +1 Interesting to see the differences in our code -- I learned a trick or two from seeing yours. An enjoyable exercise, for sure.

Comment: @gibberish Thank you, way to beat me to it!